# CRON expression for 7am to 9pm in every two hours

Tags: azure, cron, azure-functions

I'm creating an azure function which should run on every two hours from 7am to 9pm everyday. I've tried build a CRON expression for this using a [generator](https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html) but it cannot meet both conditions (every two hours and from 7am-9pm). Can somebody please help me to build the expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just list the hours explicitly:

```
0 0 7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21 * * *
```

This should also work:

```
0 0 7-21/2 * * *
```

Comment: @Amadan I used the generator linked by OP. Not sure which cron format Azure uses, so decided to stick to what was provided.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Thank you for your answer, I'm currently testing it. The '?' is not required for the **azure** cron format.

Comment: @IsuruSiriwardana Cool, will update. I checked the docs and saw that Azure does require the seconds field, so you might need to add that for the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52251178/3558960).

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this?

From 7am until 9pm (or 2100 hours) with a step value of 2 (ie. every 2 hours)

[`0 7-21/2 * * *`](https://crontab.guru/#0_7-21/2_*_*_*)

Comment: The [tool](https://crontab.guru/) you've linked with the answer is awesome

Comment: Small correction: for Azure Functions, you will need `0 0 7-21/2 * * *`, with an extra 0 at the beginning (for the seconds). Other than that this is correct.